# C function to check the validity of a date in DD.MM.YYYY format

Tags: c, datetime, validation

I was tasked with writing a function, that checks whether a date is valid in the following format: *DD.MM.YYYY*. Here's what I wrote:

```
bool isValidDate(const char* date)
{
    int a, b, c;
    size_t len = strnlen(date, 255);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(date[i]) && date[i] != '.') return false;
    }
    int validConversions = sscanf_s(date, "%2d.%2d.%4d", &a, &b, &c);
    return validConversions == 3 ? true : false;
}
```

From my testing I can conclude that this function does reasonably well: it doesn't accept anything except dots and digits, it expects to read exactly 3 numbers and it knows how many digits to read for the days and months.

Something it doesn't check however, is whether the days are less than 31 or the months are less than 12. Another thing it doesn't do is that it doesn't check correct looking, but invalid dates such as 30.02.2013 or 31.06.2012.

Solving that problem is trivial, but I don't wanna write 12 `if`s for each month to check the dates. I'm starting to think I should just generate a data structure of valid dates and use that to check, i.e. if the passed date is there, then it's valid.

Is that the best way to do it or are there other ways?

Comment: One quick remark is that you should probably use `strnlen` instead of `strlen`. If you get a string that does not contain a '\0', your function will have an undefined behavior.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker changed to `strnlen`

Comment: `strnlen(date, 0)` will *always* return `0`.

Comment: "Solving that problem is trivial, but I don't wanna write" What *do* you want? And what date range do you consider valid? Your specification is unclear, yet it appears you ask us to fix the problem for you while you haven't fixed it entirely yourself yet. That smells an awful lot like a feature request. Please clarify after reading the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @SergeyTeryan You can learn more about strnlen [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strnlen) but to summarize, `strnlen` takes a maximun length. `strnlen(date, 9)` means that it will go up to 9 character to find '\0'. So if your date is 6 bytes long for example, it will return 6. If your date is 12 bytes long, it will return 9 anyway. This prevent your code to read memory "indefinitely" if the string passed to your function is corrupted and does not contain a '\0'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to code not working since the function will always return false (strnlen will always return zero).

Comment: @pacmaninbw No need to, I'll edit it.

Comment: The edit is ok this time, but editing after the question has been answered is generally not allowed.

Comment: @Luke Using `strnlen` without passing in the length of the string to the function will invoke just as much undefined behavior as using `strlen`.

Comment: Don't use any `_s`-prefixed functions. Even though MS says the functions are "safer", in reality all the functions are just dumping a whole bunch of not-portable BS on your code.

Comment: "Solving that problem is trivial" Hoo, boy, let me show you a little something: http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time And then another one: http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Comment: @LukeSkywalker In C, all _strings_ contain a _null character_, else by definition, it is not a string.  To suggest "If you get a string that does not contain a '\0'" misleads as to what is a _string_.   Even if it is possible `char* date` does not point to a string.

Comment: SergeyTeryan Is input like `" 12.  25. 2000"` acceptable (spaces before) or an error?  How about `"12 .25 .2000"` (spaces after)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use descriptive variable names

Instead of `int a, b, c`, give them more descriptive names:

```
int day, month year;
```

## `sscanf()` will ignore trailing garbage

The function `sscanf()` will stop parsing after the last conversion. So the string `"1.2.3...."` will be cleared by your check for digits and period characters, and then `sscanf()` will read 3 integers, and returns 3. But obviously, this is an invalid date.

It would be best if you could have `sscanf()` determine the validity of the whole input string. One way is to use the `%n` conversion to check how many characters of the string were parsed so far, and then check that this corresponds to the whole string. This is how you can do that:

```
int day, month, year, chars_parsed;

if (sscanf(date, "%2d.%2d.%4d%n", &day, &month, &year, &chars_parsed) != 3)
    return false;

/* If the whole string is parsed, chars_parsed points to the NUL-byte
   after the last character in the string.
 */
if (date[chars_parsed] != 0)
    return false;
```

## You don't need 12 `if`s to check the month

You can just write:

```
if (month < 1 || month > 12)
    return false;
```

And similar for days and perhaps even years if you want to limit the allowed range.

## Avoid redundant checks

It is likely that your program will normally handle valid date strings. So you want to optimize for this case. In your code, you are checking for the string to be empty at the start, but this is not necessary; if the input string is empty, then `sscanf()` will not return 3, so it will already correctly return false. Since most input strings will be valid, checking the string length is just a waste of CPU cycles.

Similarly, checking for each character to be a digit or a period is redundant if you just use `sscanf()` with the `%n` method to check that there was no trailing garbage after the year.

## Better date checking

Just checking whether the month is between 1 and 12 and day between 1 and 31 is not enough. A given month might have less than 31 days. There are also leap years to consider. And if you want to allow dates far in the past, you run into the problem that we have had different calenders. To give an idea of how difficult the problem is, watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

One way to validate the date is to use the C library's date and time conversion routines. After scanning the day, month and year, create a `struct tm` from that, then convert it to seconds since epoch using `mktime()`. This might still accept invalid dates, but if you convert that back to a `struct tm`, you can check whether that conversion matched the original input:

```
int day, month, year,
sscanf(date, "%2d.%2d.%4d", &day, &month, &year);

struct tm input = {
    .tm_mday = day,
    .tm_mon = month - 1,
    .tm_year = year - 1900,
};

time_t t = mktime(&input); /* note, this might modify input */
struct tm *output = localtime(&t); /* prefer localtime_r() on systems that support it */

if (day != output->tm_mday || month != output->tm_mon + 1|| year != output->tm_year + 1900)
    return false;
```

These routines will probably still not handle dates hundreds of years in the past correctly, but it should suffice for recent dates.

Comment: How do we handle cases like _31.02.2019_ which are syntactically valid?

Comment: I thought `mktime()` would return an error if the date was invalid, but it does not. Perhaps using a roundtrip would work: create a `struct tm`, convert it to seconds with `mktime()`, then convert that back to `struct tm` using `localtime_r()`, and then checking whether the day/month/year match the results you got from `sscanf()`.

Comment: I'll accept that, but I have no way of testing it, as there's no `localtime_r` on windows.

Comment: Ah, but there is `localtime()`. It might be unsafe to use in threaded programs though, unless it uses thread-local storage internally.

Comment: btw the function still accepts bogus dates like _31.02.2019_

Comment: Indeed, it seems `mktime()` actually modifies the input. I changed the code to avoid comparing `input` to `output`. The manual page of `mktime()` says the input is normalized, so maybe you don't need to call `localtime()` at all.

Comment: Try not to answer questions that are off-topic. You have answered 2 questions today that would be considered off-topic.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I answered it before you decided it was off-topic. Originally the code was not always returning `false`, but the poster changed it based on the comment from Luke Skywalker.

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't the first one to decide it was off-topic. This question is off-topic for at least 3 reasons. and the original version was off-topic for two. Lack of Concrete Context, What are you asking.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Hm, I don't see any mention of off-topic or Lack of Concrete Context on this page. I only see your comment from half an hour ago about voting to make it off-topic. Am I missing something? Also, I think these comments are getting completely off-topic...

Comment: An alternative all-in-one check (for the "syntactical correctness" part) could be `if sscanf(date, "%2d.%2d.%4d%c", &day, &month, &year, &dummy_char) != 3`

Comment: That `%n` trick is wonderful.

Comment: @SergeyTeryan : not only that, but for February we have to check for leap years too.

Comment: Better code would test `mktime(&input)` for a error return of -1.

Comment: Pedantically the `mktime(&input);  localtime(&t);` trick - which used local time - fails select timezone cases that involve a timezone not having a valid time for the date and 0:0:0 hour.  I am thinking of cases where a Pacific timezone lost/gain a day switching which side of the IDL it was on.  Better to use `UTC` - if there was a convenient counter to `gmtime()`.